# Add Data in firebase after doing authentication

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

My rule looks like this -

```
{
"rules": {
    "customer": {
      "$user_id": {
            ".write": false,
            ".read" : "$user_id === auth.uid"
        }
    },
  "franchises": 
  {
        ".read":    true,
        ".write": "root.child('customer').hasChild(newData.child('salon_id').val())"
  }
 }
}
```

I want to add data in **franchises** which is having a salon_id and I want to make sure this salon_id exists in the **customer** as uid.

I am getting error

> PERMISSION_DENIED: Permission denied

**Edited with the code -**

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref('franchises');
ref.push({
    address: address,
    contact_no: contact_no,
    contact_person_name: contact_person_name,
    name: textinputPlaceName,
    salon_id: salon_id
});
```

**Data looks like this -**
[image]

Comment: Without seeing the minimal code that causes this error message it's hard to help.

Comment: What should I post the data structure?

Comment: The error message you've included is trigger when you execute a certain piece of code. You'll need to include the minimal code that triggers the problem in your question.

Comment: I think what Frank meant to say is that you should post the part of your code that actually tries to write something to firebase, since this write action is the thing being denied. In your case, it would be the code that tries adding data in franchises.

Comment: Hi @FrankvanPuffelen please check my question I have updated it with the code.

Comment: From the current information you shared it seems most likely that the salon doesn't exist under `/customer/<salon_id>`.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Added data as image you can see salon_id in the customer.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a level in your rules:

```
"franchises": {
    ".read":    true,
    ".write": "root.child('customer').hasChild(newData.child('salon_id').val())"
}
```

This applies when you write to `franchises`. But since your code calls `ref.push()`, you write one level deeper. So the rules should be:

```
 "franchises": {
    ".read":    true,
    "$franchiseId": {
      ".write": "root.child('customer').hasChild(newData.child('salon_id').val())"
    }
}
```

Comment: Same thing still getting PERMISSION_DENIED

Comment: I have only updated the rules do I need to update the code?

Comment: I am passing the $franchiseId as push() so it automatically generating might be that is causing the problem. Is it @frank?